# Disappear the value of the array from findelementsbyclassname

Tags: arrays, vba, xpath, element

```
Sub problem()

    Dim cd As WebDriver
    Dim ele As WebElement
    
    Dim dataArr(400, 3) As String
    Dim xpathstring As String
    
    Dim i, j, k, m, templow As Long
    Dim trcnt As String
    
    Set cd = New WebDriver
    cd.AddArgument "headless"
    cd.Start "chrome"
    cd.Wait 1000
    
    cd.Get "http://data.krx.co.kr/contents/MDC/MAIN/main/index.cmd"
    cd.Wait 500
           
    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input").SendKeys ("3S")
    cd.Wait 500
           
    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/button/img").Click
    cd.Wait 500

    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section[2]/section/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h4[1]/a/span").Click
    cd.Wait 500

    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section[2]/section/section/div/div/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/button[4]").Click
           
    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section[2]/section/section/div/div/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a").Click
    cd.Wait 500

    xpathstring = "/html/body/div[2]/section[2]/section/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody"
    j = 1
   trcnt = 1
   For Each ele In cd.FindElementsByClass("CI-GRID-EVEN")
        dataArr(j, 1) = ele.FindElementByXPath("" + xpathstring + "/tr[" + trcnt + "]/td[1]").Text
        dataArr(j, 2) = ele.FindElementByXPath("" + xpathstring + "/tr[" + trcnt + "]/td[5]").Text
        dataArr(j, 3) = ele.FindElementByXPath("" + xpathstring + "/tr[" + trcnt + "]/td[2]").Text
        Debug.Print dataArr(j, 1); dataArr(j, 2); dataArr(j, 3); trcnt; j
        j = j + 1
        trcnt = trcnt + 2
   Next ele
End Sub
```

The values of the elements array to 10th are normal, but there is no value from the 11th array. The trcnt and j are printed normally, and the number of array is 63. Where are they from 11th to 63th values ? Help me !!!

Comment: Please show more of your code as well as the url if possible. We should be able to reproduce your problem. See [mcve]. What does 11th array mean? `dataArr(11,3)` ? What does the number of the array mean? That the array is `dataArr(63,3)` in size?

Comment: The html of the table? Not as an image but inserted using the snippet tool via [edit].

Comment: from 11th to 63th values of ele.FindElementByXPath("" + xpathstring + "/tr[" + trcnt + "]/td[1]").Text are all blanks. But from 1st to 10th values are normal. I defined dataArr(400,3) as string. Thanks.

Comment: This step `cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/section[2]/section/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h4[1]/a/span").Click` doesn't appear to find an element for me. Are you simply getting only page 1 results?

Comment: 2021/12/283,3553,1901 1 
2021/12/243,2303,2903 2 
2021/12/223,2653,2255 3 
2021/12/203,2803,2507 4 
2021/12/163,3103,3209 5 
2021/12/143,4053,39011 6 
2021/12/103,4903,43013 7 
2021/12/083,5003,46515 8 
2021/12/063,5203,49517 9 
2021/12/023,4003,50519 10 
21 11 
23 12

Comment: I would also move away from using such long xpaths in favour of short, more robust, css selectors, or even short xpaths (less preferable).

Comment: The above is the result of debug.print in the code. From 11th.... no data but trcnt/j.

Comment: e.g. to use input box a shorter, more robust method, `cd.FindElementById("jsTotSch").SendKeys ("3S")` , and to search `cd.FindElementByCss("[title=Search]").click`. After search click you can use a wait for presence of element/element visible for `cd.FindElementByCss(".searchTb table")` as that is the results table.

Comment: `Set table = cd.FindElementByCss(".searchTb table")` then `Dim tr As WebElement : For Each tr in table.FindElementsByCss("tbody tr")` to loop through rows.

Comment: To get next page `cd.FindElementByCss(".jsNext").click`